# Windows 8.1 powering off USB Drives

Tags: windows, hard-drive, usb, windows-8.1

Since upgrading to 8.1, Windows will shut down my hard drive bay connected by USB after about 10 minutes. I didn't have this issue in Windows 8 as I just went in and changed the hard drive sleep time to Never. However Windows 8.1 seems to be ignoring this and powering off my USB drives. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: which machine ? Which model ?

Comment: Home made computer.

Comment: Now this would be too silly to ask but I hope you have tried different ports

Comment: I have USB 3 and USB 2

Comment: I cannot answer due to reputation < 10; however, this is a bug in Windows 8.1 and you can find out more here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1_pr-hardware/i-just-installed-windows-81-and-now-my-external/8f113942-2a20-48ab-96fc-f169e8814719?rtAction=1379385636471

Comment: @MichaelMortensen thanks, I was starting to come to that conclusion as I had read some more online about it. Looks like I'll be installing Windows 8 tonight to fix the problem.

Comment: Possibly related:  http://superuser.com/questions/663103/linux-wd30ezrx-wd-green-hdd-blacx-duet-5g-usb/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across the blog post *[Help! After installing Windows 8.1, my USB drive disappears or file transfers stop unexpectedly…](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/usbcoreblog/archive/2013/11/01/help-after-installing-windows-8-1-my-usb-drive-disappears-or-file-transfers-stop-unexpectedly-r-a-post-title.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage)* when trying to resolve problems with my Seagate Expansion 3 TB drive which would power down after several minutes with no access despite power save setting set to "never" shut down.

This began happening after doing a fresh install of Windows 8.1. I followed instructions concerning a registry hack and the problem has been fixed.

Comment: +1: Setting the registry key seems to be the only thing that works in my case. Settings in "Power Options" as well as power settings for the USB Root Hubs didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Thank you, that has resolved the issue for myself as well.  +1.

Comment: According to the updated reference, this is no longer required - "The registry workaround described in this blog is no longer required. A major Windows update published on 2014-04-08 reverts the USBSTOR.SYS driver behavior to 8.0."

Comment: Link only answers are not acceptable here, please add important parts in the link to your answer please

Comment: Answers like this are frustrating, in this case, I am interested in the solution you submitted, but the website failed to load for me.

Answer (score 2):

Go into [Device Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager), click on *Universal Serial Bus controllers*, right click (or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd>) on each of the entries labeled ***USB Root Hub***, choose *Properties*, and click on tab *Power Management*. Make sure the check mark in "Allow computer to turn off device" DOES NOT HAVE A CHECK.

Do that for every USB Root Hub device in Device Manager. Your external hard disk drive will no longer shut off.

[image: Screenshot from Windows Device Manager]

Comment: Awesome I'll try that out when I get home tonight.

Comment: That did not solve the problem.

Comment: Same with me .. it did not solve the problem at all :(

Comment: @Rumel - Helps if you provide more detail then "it didn't work" did it make any difference?

Comment: There was no difference at all. They still shut off after a bit.