# Windows 10 anniversary update powering off USB hard drive enclosure

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, usb, windows-10-v1607

After updating to Windows 10 anniversary my Mediasonic ProBox HF2-SU3S2 4 Bay 3.5" Hard Drive Enclosure powers off after about 15 minutes. I had the same issue in Windows 10 1511 but was able to fix it using
[Windows 8.1 powering off USB Drives](https://superuser.com/questions/663511/windows-8-1-powering-off-usb-drives)
This no longer works in the anniversary update. Is there a new fix in the anniversary update?

Comment: the problem is when these guys are release upgrade or an update , hardware firms are not ready with drivers

Comment: Did you try going to **Power Options**,**Change Plan Settings**,**Change Advanced power Settings**,and finally the screen we wanted.  Expand **Hard disk**, then expand **Turn off hard disk after**, and finally increase the number of minutes to whatever you want.  **Never** is below 0, then click **Apply** and **Ok**.  Close any leftover screens.  It saves wear and tear on your hard drive to left windows turn it off, so I would suggest letting it after some interval.